# WSO2 JWTGenerator and APIMgtGatewayJWTGeneratorImpl

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Сan someone explain to me the difference between JWTGenerator and APIMgtGatewayJWTGeneratorImpl classes?

I updated wso2 from version 2.6.0 to 4.1.0 and there was only this JWTGenerator generator class, but now it does not work.

*Ref: https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/deploy-and-publish/deploy-on-gateway/api-gateway/passing-enduser-attributes-to-the-backend-via-api-gateway/#sample-jwt*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In early versions of WSO2 API Manager, it has opaque token support. So if you are migrating to latest APIM version and still want to use opaque tokens instead of the JWT tokens, you have to use the class JWTGenerator. If you look at the package of this class, it is org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.token. So token generation happens at the key manager(KM) side. When an opaque token is used in an API call, the gateway calls the key manager to validates the opaque token and also it generates a backend JWT. Then the gateway receives the backend JWT for a valid access token from the KM and GW sends the Backend JWT to the backend service.
Refer - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/deploy-and-publish/deploy-on-gateway/api-gateway/passing-enduser-attributes-to-the-backend-via-api-gateway/#customizing-the-jwt-generation-completely

If you are using JWT access tokens to access APIs, then you should use APIMgtGatewayJWTGeneratorImpl. When an access token comes to the gateway, it validates the token itself and generates a backend JWT. So this class is used.
Refer - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/deploy-and-publish/deploy-on-gateway/api-gateway/passing-enduser-attributes-to-the-backend-via-api-gateway/#jwt-self-contained-access-tokens

Answer (score 2):

We have done a major architectural redesign (Please refer [this](https://wso2.com/ibrary/articles/wso2-api-manager-embracing-event-driven-architecture/)) to the gateway and keymanager components in the latest versions of the product. One of the key changes is to make the gateway run independently without connecting to the keymanager node. For that, one change introduced is JWT tokens (instead of opaque tokens which were used in older versions). With the introduction of this, all the token validation happens within the gateway node without needing to connect to the keymanager node.

Previously (versions before 3.2.0) the backend JWT was generated in the keymanager node. For that `JWTGenerator` is used. Now since everything happens in the gateway node, this backend jwt is also generated from the gateway node. For that, we use this `APIMgtGatewayJWTGeneratorImpl` class (which is extended from the parent class [AbstractAPIMgtGatewayJWTGenerator](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/v9.20.74/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.common.gateway/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/common/gateway/jwtgenerator/AbstractAPIMgtGatewayJWTGenerator.java) )

Hope you understood why your custom JWTGenerator from API Manager 2.6.0 is not working in the latest version. You will have to create a new custom JWT generator as mentioned in this [doc](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/deploy-and-publish/deploy-on-gateway/api-gateway/passing-enduser-attributes-to-the-backend-via-api-gateway/#jwt-self-contained-access-tokens)